# Importance of Chinnamasta Sadhana

Tags: tantra, shakti, chinnamasta

In which avastha/bhaava does Chinnamasta falls? Does it belong to `Srividya Krama`?
Its heard that, people should not go for this Sadhana for "getting things done" --experiencing materialistic pleasures!

Is it termed as "dangerous" similar to " `Yakshini Sadhana` (`karnayakshi` kind of...)" 
and what dangers we encounter,if we start Chinnamasta Moolamantra jaap.

Comment: The greater the danger, the greater the reward. That said, it would seem she's not one to suffer a fool gladly. Cobras can produce help produce antivenom, but I wouldn't grab the first one I saw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In which avastha/bhaava does Chinnamasta falls? Does it belong to
>   Srividya Krama?

No, she belongs to the Dakshina-amnaya, as pointed out by Partha. Whereas Tripura Sundari is an Urdha-amnaya Goddess.

VAravAnaliya Tantram gives the following Amanya-Bheda:

> DakshinAkAli, BagalAmukhi, ChinnamastA, TArA, MAtangi and BhadrA are
>   deities of Dakshina-Amnaya (Southern amnaya). Shodashi and Bhairavi
>   are Urdha-Amanya (higher amnaya) Goddesses whereas Bhuvaneswari,
>   AnnapurnA etc are Purva-Amnaya (eastern amnaya) Devis.

So, ChinnamastA has separate worship.

### ChinnamastA or ChinnamastikA (also known as Prachanda ChandikA) is a Supreme Goddess

She is the 6th MahAvidyA.

The **Shakti Samgama Tantram 4.51** states about her the following:

> yatha chinnA tathA kAli tathaiva sundari parA |
>  Tathaiva tArA
>   samdishtA chaturthanAm nahi bhinnatA ||
>
> Who is ChinnA she is KAli
>   and she is the supreme Tripura Sundari and she is again TArA -- **Among
>   these four, there is no difference.**

So, to compare such a Goddess to Yakshini is not at all right.

In Bhairava Tantra's "Chinnamasta Trailokya Mohana Kavacha", we find that the Trinities worship the Goddess.

We have the verses:

> Trailokyavijayam nAma kavacham sarvamohanam |
>  Sarva vidyAmayam
>   sAkshAt surAsurajayapradam ||
>  DhAranAt pathanAdisha
>   trailokyavijayi vibhuh |
>  BrahmA nArAyano rudro dhArnAt pathanad
>   yatoh ||
>
> This armour named "Trailokyamohana' is capable of enchanting all. It
>   is endowed with all-knowledge and gives victories over Devas and
>   Asuras. The one who reads it or wears it becomes the winner of the
>   three-worlds. Lord Brahma, NArAyana and Rudro all wear and read it.

### Goddess ChinnamAsta's worship and Mantra

The most celebrated mantra (or VidyA) for the Goddess is a 16-letter mantra. This mantra is mentioned in YAmala Tantrams as well as in Viswa SAra Tantram.

The greatness of this VidyA is as follows:

> prachandachandikAm vakshye sarva kAma-phalapradAm |
>  YasyAh
>   prasAda mAtrena shiva eva bhaven narah ||
>  aputro labhate putram
>   dhano dhanamApnuyAt|
> Kavitvam cha supAndityam labhate nAtra
>   samshayah ||
>
> By simply getting the grace of the all-desire-fulfilling Prachanda
>   ChadikA (or ChinnamastA) a man becomes Shiva. The childless gets
>   child; the poor gets wealth and expertise in poetry and scholarly acts
>   are obtained without doubt.
>
> **PurashcharjArnava, Taranga 9**

The mantra itself (in codes) and it's various applications are found in the following verses:

> Lakshmi lajjAm tato mAyAm mAtrAdvAdasikAmatha |
>  Vajravairochaniye
>   cha mAye phat swAhayA yute || (mantra code ends here)
>  Lakshmi bijam yadA AdyAm syAt tadA
>   shrih sarvatomukhi ||
>  LajjA bijena chAdyena vasyatAm yAnti
>   yoshitah ||
>  MAyAbijena chAdyena mahApAtakanAshanam |
>   MAtrAdvAdashikAbijamAdyAm syAnmuktidAyakam ||
>
> If Shrim is at the start [of the mantra], [the mantra] gives all-round
>   prosperity; if Klim is at the start, it gives the power of attracting
>   all women; If Hrim is at the start, then it destroys all mortal sins;
>   and if Aim is at the start, the mantra is giver of liberation.

And, if Om is at the start of the mantra then that is a giver of Bhukti-Mukti both.

> TArAdyA shodashi chyAnyA bhavet sapta dashAkshari |
>  EshA vidyA
>   mahAvidyA bhuktimukti kari sadA ||
>
> If OM is added at the start of the 16-letter VidyA of ChinnamstA, then
>   that mantra becomes giver of worldly pleasures and liberation both.
>
> **ViswasAra Tantram verse quoted in the same text**

There are other mantras for the Goddess given in MahAkAla SamhitA etc.

### ChinnamastA - the most fierce deity

ChinnamastA is by far the most terrible deity. So, no weak hearted person may embark upon her worship. It can be fatal, if things are done without proper knowledge, and without a competent Guru's guidance.

For this point it's stated:

> **NAtah paratarA kAchidugrA devi bhavishyati** |
>  TasmAd asaktairmanur janai grAhyeyam kathanchana ||
>  SiddhirvA mrityurapi
>   vA dvayorekataram bhavet |
>
> **There is no deity which is more fierce than ChinnamastA**. That is why the faint-hearted must never accept her mantra and worship her. In
>   her SAdhanA, either Siddhi or death is inevitable.

Further, we also have the following warning regarding the ferocity of the Goddess:

> PrachandachandikAmeva dhyAtvA yastu na pujayet |
>  sadyastasya
>   shirashchitvA devi pivati shonitam ||
>
> Without DhyAnam other deities can still be be worshipped. But, who
>   does not worship Goddess Chinnamsta duly with her DhyAnam, will get
>   his head chopped off.

So, better stay away from her worship unless you have the guidance of a highly competent Guru.

Comment: The last line means Devi drinks his blood instantly by chopping off tye head

Comment: What is the difference between Lajja bija and Maya bija BTW?

Comment: "But, who does not worship Goddess Chinnamsta duly with her DhyAnam, will get his head chopped off !!" , its very shocking and scary!!

Comment: @SaMolPP Yes scary indeed .. Chinnamsta worship shd therefore be done after lots of thought .. and under competent guidance ..

Comment: @Partha Yes, I  omitted intentionally the meaning of "devi pivati shonitam"

Comment: Lajja Bija is the same as Kama bija here that is KLIM @Partha Maya Bija of course is HRIM

Comment: @Rickross i think Hri means lajja in sanskrit

Comment: But here Lajja Bija is KILM .. @Pratimaputra

Comment: @Rickross okay whatever Shiva says is final.And there is the possibility of getting the head chopped off:(

Comment: "NAtah paratarA kAchidugrA.. " Could you please tell me, from which śāstra is this taken?

Comment: It is from a Tantra .. need to see if the name of the Tantra is mentioned or not @Bingming

Answer (score 3):

First I am narrating an incident from the biography of Sri Sri Bamakhepa:

> Once the bengali inhabitatants of Jamalpur, Bihar decided to worship Devi Chinnamasta instead of Maa Kali on the Kalipuja night.But soon after the puja, cholera broke out and many people started losing their lives.The people involved were advised to go to some siddha Tantrik for help and they came to Tarapith where the famous Tantrik saint Bamakhepa resided, Hearing from them everything, He opined:The fools wanted to catch a cobra while they are not capable of catching even a venomless snake. He went there and worshipped Maa Chinnamasta and everything became okay. (Reference:Mahapith Tarapith, Bipulkumar Gangopadhyay, Jay Tara Publishers).

This points to the dangers of doing the Tantrik Pujas ignorantly, especially of Devi Chinnamasta.She is normally worshipped by the Aghoris and was the Ishtadevi of Sri Ramanath Aghori Baba.(Ibid.)

**Devi Chinnamasta belongs to the Dakshina-Amnaya while worshipping Sri or Shodashi is a part of the Purva-Amnaya.So Chinnamasta is not related to Sri** **Vidya** (Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana,Upendrakumar Das, Vol. 1, page 459).

Chinnamasta is called Prachanda-Chandika also.According to the Purascharyarnava,

> She fulfills all desires of the devotees. Child, wealth, knowledge --everything can be gained from Her worship(Ibid. page 506).

But no Tantrik puja or sadhana should be done without proper guidance from an able Guru.Otherwise what might happen has been narrated in the incident mentioned above.

However, She is one form of the Dasa-Mahavidyas and so able to give both bhukti and Mukti if worshipped properly and should not be compared to Yakshinis.

Comment: The above incident also tell us that the path of Tantra is not easy to follow. Hence, several gurus, saints and even avatars suggested that it would be better to adopt the path of Bhakti. Results might be delayed but there's very little chance of going astray.