# What's the relation between Chhinnamasta and Kali?

Tags: kali, dasha-mahavidya, chinnamasta

What's the relation between [Chhinnamasta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhinnamasta) and [Kali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali) ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: Among Dasha Mahavidyas, Kali is the first Mahavidya whereas Chinnamasta is the 6th one. Some Tantras say that there is no difference between the two Goddesses (See- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33796) but still they are different with different mantras and procedures of worship. You can see this too: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33796