# Can I worship Chinnamasta?

Tags: worship, devi, guru, shakti, dasha-mahavidya

I am very fascinated towards Maa chinnamasta!

But after searching about her,I found out that she is the most terrible deity to invoke without a Guru

I came across a mantra on youtube 'Chinnamasta Gaytri Mantra' The mantra gave me immense happiness
after chanting it! and now I am in this dilemma to worship or not to worship, Internet has Mixed answers. Any help is appreciated

Few things about me!

I am a complete beginner I began from worshipping Hanuman Ji,(mid june 2022) come across krishna  but gradually turned towards shakti!

I really wanna devote myself to Maa chinnamasta but well am scared aswell!

No'I am not Initiated as a Tantaric.

Yes'my fascination can be a product of how chinnamasta is depicted, the first time I saw her I was flabbergasted but in a +ve manner!

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: No don't chant her gayatri mantra on your own... chant her ashttotar satnamavali(108 names) one name everyday for atleast 108 times she will guide you.. don't get impatient its possible that after just one day of chanting you get initiated into her worship or it can even take 100 yrs just trust her you will get your guru/initiation when you're ready so don't give up keep chanting her names

Comment: I love Maa Chinnmasta and all the MahaVidya but yeah, I’d be slightly careful with this, maybe look up some info & Hindu texts to find out more before you go into it. If you search on here and online there’s lots you can access and slowly start reading to understand, a lot of the guidelines and rules are explained in full 

Comment: There is fear created around her worship in scriptures see this (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33796/4732). So very unsure about whether you should go ahead or not. Unless you get a Guru's guidance it's preferable not to proceed too further. Although IMO this fear is created so that not everyone worships her. Because Chinnamsta worship results in Moksha certainly. But not everyone is eligible for Moksha yet. But whatever it is you need to be cautious.

Comment: @AbhinavRaj Thank you for your reply! appreciate the help

Comment: @devibhakt Yes,That's the reason I am not being hasty and chanting anything youtube has to offer, It's crazy some channels even tell to chant Beej mantra and that's scary!

Comment: "There is no deity which is more fierce than ChinnamastA. That is why the faint-hearted must never accept her mantra and worship her. In her SAdhanA, either Siddhi or death is inevitable." This quote shook me... am worried now XD

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Monk Yeah I understand, and Chinnmasta Maa is one of my all time favorites. I think it’s good you posted this question, check with guys on here like Naruto, Rickross, Savdy, Chamunda Das and several others, they know what’s up. I’m brand new Shakta and I’ve found their replies and comments really helpful, still have so so much to learn 